# Trying to make routes dependent on logged in user roles

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to come up with a way to update routes in react-router after a user logs in and I know what roles the user has.

I was hoping that there would be an API where I could add appropriate routes after the user logs in but no luck there.

I'm currently thinking that I could use the lazy loading so that I originally load the root Route which has a child for each role, then in the definition of those children could use getChildRoutes to test for the presence of the required role before lazy loading the allowed routes.

Has anyone implemented something like this and have a working/better solution?

Comment: Why not just have static routes, and have your components handle logged in/out?

Comment: I'm looking at mixing multiple user 'roles' including some with higher access level. My preference is to not define sensitive routes rather than have a test at the component level. I wanted to start with a minimal set of routes addressing auth when no user is logged in, and then add the appropriate routes once I know what roles the user has. So it's more about the roles and rights they confer than whether the user is logged in/out.

Comment: I recommend taking a look at React-Router's provided [`auth-flow`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/auth-flow) example.

Comment: already using that approach for auth, but it doesn't allow me to specify which roles are required for each route. I could include the user's roles in the location state, but that doesn't help me specify which role is required to access a particular route